# Como fazer uma Janela ficar sempre acima das outras no PYQT5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt-5

Estou criando uma pequena aplicação e preciso que a janela principal fique sempre acima das demais, qual atributo usar no pyqt 5 ?
Desde de já agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Não existe garantia que vá ficar no topo sempre, ainda mais se outros programas usarem do mesmo recurso, eu vou ter que ser um pouco mais sincero a respeito disso, programas no topo sempre me aborreceram, eu sou o usuário, eu sei o que eu quero no topo e o que eu não quero, claro que se for uma opção dentro do programa escolhida pelo usuário seria aceitável usar isso, mas se for forçadamente e não uma opção do usuário eu me recusaria a usar o tal programa.

Voltando a parte técnica, basicamente a flag para deixar no topo é `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint`

```
<objeto>.setWindowFlags(<objeto>.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

Troque `<objeto>` pelo contexto (widget ou QMainWindow) que vai aplicar, lembrando que um mesmo programa pode ter várias janelas, um exemplo básico:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
w.resize(800, 600)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note que usei `.windowFlags()` para obter as flags padrões, para então com o `|` "combinar" com `QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint`.

Quase tudo do Qt em C++ em aplicável de forma semelhante no PyQt5 e como alternativa ao PyQt também existe o pyside, que é bastante semelhante, então consultar a documentação oficial da Qt pode lhe ajudar:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html